# Very slow ajax response on yii framework

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, yii

i am having strange issue with yii framework. on localhost, ajax response takes 200ms (which is fast and i am satsified) where as on my live server, same function take 4 to 7 seconds.

**below is my php ajax function:-**

```
public function actionOpenpopup() {
                    $this->checkAjaxRequest();                  

                    $user_id = $_GET['uid'];

                    $rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                              ->select('*')
                              ->from('saved_designs')
                              ->where('uid=:id', array(':id' => $user_id))
                              ->order('date desc')
                              ->queryAll();

                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($rows as $row) {
                              $rows[$i] = $row;
                              $i++;
                    }
                    if ($rows) {
                              echo json_encode($rows);
                    }
                    else
                              echo json_encode(null);
          }



 function checkAjaxRequest() {
                        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
                                  header('Content-Type: application/json; charset="UTF-8"');
                                  return true;
                        } else {
                                  throw new CHttpException('403', 'Forbidden Access');
                                  exit;
                        }
              }
```

**javascript code is:-**

```
function sendAjaxCall(data){

$.ajax({
                                type : 'GET',
                                url : 'index.php/request/openpopup',
                                datatype : 'json',
                                data :data,
                 success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);                      
                        }
});    

}
```

****Note:- So far database has only 10 to 20 records. Also On live server, all my ajax calls give me slow response.***

Comment: this has nothing to do with Java. could you check in the Chrome Network console which part of the request takes time? If it's the DNS lookup etc

Comment: Maybe you have bad internet or host slowed by something(alot of requests for ex.)

Comment: Judging from having the same code on local and live server, it's safe to assume that it's not the code. That means it's the server or the connectivity between you and live server. If you're on a shared hosting environment, it's possible that there's another vhost taking up resources.

Comment: thanks for your replies. i am using Amazon Ec2 server. my other projects are running fine. but this one (yii based) is having some issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a few things. First off after you `echo` your json I would kill your script to make sure nothing else runs:

```
if ($rows) {
    echo json_encode($rows);
    die();
}
```

Also on your `index.php` make sure you have the site taken out of debug mode, if you have either of the middle two lines that start with `defined()` enabled each page load Yii is recreating cached files and it can take a while, especially if you have extensions like bootstrap included. I have had this exact issue when doing some work for someone and their site was hosted on GoDaddy. For some reason the file creation was really slow and was really dragging everything.

```
<?php
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/test.php';

//defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
//defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Also are any other functions running slow? Any errors in your error log?

Another option to help debug create another action that doesn't require a AJAX call. It is much easier to debug this way instead of relying on ajax, plus it helps you narrow down the source of the problem. Plus don't know why but you get your array of rows then re-populate your array of rows, this is very redundant.

```
public function actionCheckpopup() {
    $user_id = $_GET['uid'];

    $rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('*')
            ->from('saved_designs')
            ->where('uid=:id', array(':id' => $user_id))
            ->order('date desc')
            ->queryAll();

    echo json_encode($rows);
    die();
}
```

Then simply use a browser and go to `http://yoursite.com/index.php/request/checkpopup?uid=1`

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining in detail. i commented the two lines which you pointed out, but it did not solve my problem. response is slow. yes database and code are on same server (amazon EC2)

Comment: hi  Pitchinnate , i try to call that using using direct link (as you said) , and it generate result very fast approx 1 to 2 secs. so one thing is sure that server response is good but Ajax call takes alot of time. any solution?

Comment: I would install firebug on Chrome or Firefox and watch the console you should see the Ajax request go out and come back. It may help you find something.

Comment: i already did that. nothing found. all i can see is that ajax takes 4 to 7 seconds and then resposne generated. thats what firebug told

Comment: Did you modify your `actionOpenpopup()` and fix the way `$rows` is populated? Only other thing I can think of is to start adding some timestamps in the code and including that in the json array that gets sent back so you can see which parts of the code are taking a long time.

Comment: i have done everything, but still server response is slow. here are my server stats, may be my server specs are low:-  cpu cores 1, RAM 600MB

Comment: Just for fun I would try a different browser to see if it makes any difference. You should also be able to watch the Network tab in Chrome and see if most of the time is waiting for DNS lookup, or Connection, or Data.

Comment: thanks alot Pitchinnate , i found the issue its the Query that is bringing unnecessary coloumns (which contain 1000 + characters ) .