# Vue application has too slow routing

Tags: vuejs2, yii2, vue-router

I have a Vue application on frontend and php Yii2 on backend.
Each route from Vue to Yii2 has approximately time from 3 to 5 seconds.
I found one solution on stackoverflow
[Very slow ajax response on yii framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055742/very-slow-ajax-response-on-yii-framework)
but it hadn't helped me.
On frontend in my vue.config.js I have proxy settings:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost"
      }
    },
```

Maybe, I have problems from the proxy?

Comment: not a VueJS expert, but do your requests send `options` request before the actual request in console?

Comment: How have you come to this decision? Have you tried accessing your api directly? If so, what is the response time? And how does that differ from your proxy response times?

Comment: @Valerii Voronkov Have you tried to ask on https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewforum.php?f=19, there are couple of people which contribute to yii2 development, so they may have an adequate answer for your question

Comment: I don't know - where is the 'weak place' - on frontend part or on the backend.

Comment: Cue, in the browser when I access directly to api, time has the same value - from 2000+ ms to 4000

Comment: Try using the Yii2 debug module to identify the bottleneck (assuming it's even on the server side). This is an invaluable tool that saves hours of tedious debugging.